# Verify forces lazy initialization of services

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Firstly, thank you- I have become a better programmer by being "forced to" by Simple Injector.

Very early in the bootstrap of my program I setup my root container and shortly afterward call `container.Verify()`

Many of my services take a dependency on (my class) `ICurrentUser` which has methods to retrieve account secrets and configuration. As would be expected these secret are available only after the user has authenticated, which has not occurred during the bootstrapping and call `container.Verify()`.

example:

```
private readonly string serviceAccount;

public SomeService(ICurrentUser currentUser) {
    serviceAccount = currentUser.GetSecret("SomeServiceAccount");
}
```

This has caused me to change the above to:

```
private Lazy<string> serviceAccount;

public SomeService(ICurrentUser currentUser) {
    serviceAccount = 
        new Lazy<string>(() => currentUser.GetSecret("SomeServiceAccount"));
}
```

and then refer to serviceAccount.Value when it is needed.
This seems a bit awkward and complicates the ctor. Alternatively I could postpone the verify until after the user authenticates but I don't really like that as it postpones what should happen after setting up the ctor.

Is there a way for me to split the verify process into an initial lightweight verification of the service relationships but not execute the constructors until a later step?

Answer (score 1):

Constructors should be free of any logic, other than doing precondition checks and storing incoming dependencies, as explained [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) by Mark Seemann. This means that you should not make any calls to injected dependencies from inside the constructor, because:

- Such invocation might fail, causing the construction of object graphs to become unreliable
- During creation of the component, the injected dependency graph graph might, at that point, not yet be fully initialized, which makes the constructor fragile.
- Invocation of dependencies can cause constructors to depend on the availability of runtime data (such as your user's secrets), or the availability of external resources (such as a database), making it much harder to verify your container's configuration, which is something you are already experiencing. Component's constructors, however, should not rely on the availability of runtime data, as I explained [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

The solution to this problem simply is to store the incoming `ICurrentUser` dependency in the `SomeService` class, and only call its `GetSecret` method when one of `SomeService`'s methods are invoked.

You might be tempted to make loading of the value lazy, especially to prevent having to load it over and over again, which can happen if `GetSecret` is called many times throughout the lifetime of `SomeService`.

You should, however, refrain from implementing caching at that level, because that would complicate `SomeService` and all other consumers of `ICurrentUser`. Instead, you should either implement caching *inside* the `ICurrentUser` implementation -or- wrap the implementation in a Decorator that adds the caching behavior. Registering decorators in Simple Injector is [trivial](https://simpleinjector.org/aop).

Comment: Actually, my implantation of ICurrentUser does cache the values so there is no performance issue with getting rid of my Lazy<> as you suggested.  Thanks for taking the time with such a clear answer